# Delphi XE2 Style: Main Menu Ignored

Tags: delphi, menu, delphi-xe2, vcl-styles

I have applied a style to a VCL application in Delphi XE2, but it works OK, but it seems that the main menu has ignored the style. See attached image.  Is this a normal behavior?[image]

Any advice on how to apply style to the main menu?

Comment: See [`this comment`](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2012/03/06/adding-vcl-styles-support-to-a-tpopupmenu-in-2-lines-of-code/#comment-1756). Rodrigo suggests there to use `TActionMainMenuBar` instead of `TMainMenu`. But he'll be soon or later here with the answer, I'd say :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a limitation of the `TMainMenuBarStyleHook` Vcl Style hook. The normal approach to fix this kind of issue is create and register new `TMainMenu` Style hook, but unfortunately this Vcl Style hook is used internally by the `TFormStyleHook` (the vcl style hook of the forms), so this will require which you create a new form style hook as well and this implies a lot of work.

So my suggestion is replace the `TMainMenu` for a `TActionMainMenuBar` component which works very well with the vcl styles.

[image]

Comment: perhaps you can use in-memory patching instead of re-creating form hook from scratch ?

Comment: In this particular case, patching the method in memory using a detour will require a similar effort than writing the Vcl Style Hook from scratch.